# React-Redux, how to subscribe to changes in state and apply actions

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I am building a grid and a filters component using react, redux and material-ui

Here is how my filters state object in redux looks like

```
{
   1: {id:1, name:'firstName', value:'John'}
   2: {id:2, name:'LastName', value:'Doe'}
}
```

Items object in the store

```
{
   12: {id:12, firstName:'John', lastName:'Doe', contact:''}
   13: {id:13, firstName:'Mark', lastName:'Doyle', contact:''}
 }
```

when ever the state of filters object changes in the store, I want execute applyFilters function to narrowdown items. What is the best pattern for subscribing to changes in a state object and executing an action to update the state of another object in a store? or is there a better way to handle this?

**Current Implementation**

I am not sure if this an anti-pattern to access state in action creator.

```
export function updateFilters(namespace, filter, filterText) { 

    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        // To update filters object in the store
        dispatch({
            type: `${namespace}/${UPDATE_FILTERS}`,
            value: filterText,
            payload: filter.get('id')
        })

        //Actual filtering
        let state = getState();
        let filters = state[`${namespace}`].filters;
        let items = state[`${namespace}`].items;
        let filteredItems = applyFilters(items, filters);

        // To update filteredItems in the store
        dispatch({
            type: `${namespace}/${APPLY_FILTERS}`,
            payload: filteredItems
        })
    }   
}
```

Comment: I would definitely advise leaving all state manipulation in the reducer. I don't actually see where you are updating the state though. Is that happening in applyFilters()?

Answer (score 2):

Updated answer provided your feedback and added context. You can dispatch the second action from the reducer passing in your filter object as a parameter.

for example:

```
function reducer1(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
       case UPDATE_ITEMS:
          +//dispatch 2nd action and pass filtered object as parameter
          +//the 2nd action can update the item object
          -//update items object
       default:
          return state
    }
}
```

There is a lot of back and forth here, so I'm going to detail an example of how I would do this given that you want to populate your store once and work on an in-memory object afterwards.

Event Handler:

```
handleFilterChange = (filterText) => {
    this.props.updateFilter(filterText);
}
```

Action:

```
export function updateItem(filterText) {
    // you could dispatch another action, but not sure why you would
    return { 
        type: UPDATE_FILTER, filterText, 
    };
}
```

Reducer:

```
function updateFilterAndItem(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case UPDATE_FILTER:
            {
                const newItems = state.items.filter(text => state.items.includes(action.filterText));
                return Object.assign(
                    {}, 
                    state, 
                    { 
                        items: newItems,
                        filter: action.filterText
                    });
            }
    }
}
```

This is as close an answer as I can give you based on what you're trying to do, but I would ask you to rethink this. Why keep filter text in a redux store at all? Every time the event handler is called, the entire text string will be passed down the stack anyway. I want to answer your question as best I can to the guidelines of StackOverflow, but I also want to challenge you to think about your implementation, and if there might be a simple way to achieve your desired results.

Comment: I have both filters and items in redux store. When the value of filter changes, an action creator will be called and then a reducer which updates the corresponding value in filters object in the redux store. What I am trying is to trigger a function whenever this happens and update the items object in the redux store

Comment: I'm not sure this is answering your initial question, but why not just use the filter to query the data again, or use the filter on the object in memory? Would you like an example?

Comment: Items object in store is created on the initial load and every-time a filter happens the data stored in redux store is narrowed down based on applied filter value. So I don't query to fetch data on filter actions. What I am trying here is maintain the state of filters in redux and whenever state changes happen to filters object, apply an action to items in the store

Comment: thanks for your response. Currently in my filter action method I am dispatching two times, one for updating filters and another for updating items using redux-thunk and my code currently looks close to what you provided. I am checking instead of firing synchronous dispatches from action method, if there is a better way to update the state of one object based on changes to the state of another object by subscribing directly without having two round trips